# Excel vba strip numbers from string

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me write vba code for convert A column to B column like image, i have tried but can not do.

[image]

A column data 01A+00022.00 i want to convert to it 22 to B column

Comment: Have a read of this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you run into problems.  We can help you with code you are trying to write, but this is not a free code-writing service. Please read the help articles referenced in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Put below formula to `B1` cell then Drag and down

```
=VALUE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("+",A1)),MID(A1,SEARCH("+",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("+",A1)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",A1)),MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-",A1)),"")))
```

[image]